# Google Окно запроса доступа OAuth

Tags: google-oauth2

Пытаюсь настроить регистрацию на сайте через учетную запись Google. Сайт на битриксе, с ним проблем нет. Проблема в том что - *Не сохраняются настройки окна запроса доступа OAuth.*

Создал на https://console.developers.google.com новый проект. API никакие не включал. Далее захожу в "Учетные данные" -> "+Создать учетные данные" -> "Идентификатор клиента OAuth". Появляется сообщение: "Чтобы создать идентификатор клиента OAuth, укажите название продукта для окна запроса доступа." и ссылка для настройки. Заходим в настройку "Окно запроса доступа OAuth", выбираем "Внешнее. Для всех пользователей с аккаунтом Google." Попадаем на форму, где указываем название, логотип, ссылку и т.д.

Вот тут и возникает проблема. неважно какие данные я указываю, даже просто одно только название, всегда одинаковая ошибка :The request failed because changes to one of the field of the resource is not supported.

Не понятно на какие поля он ругается. Пробовал включать API Gmail и Google+, без изменений, ошибка все та же. Сделал подтверждение домена через днс, в списке разрешенных появился, но тоже не помогло. Пробовал не заполнять ничего кроме названия, тоже мимо. Вобщем спасите помогите :) Что-то явно я сделал не так, но в упор не вижу что.

Comment: Была такая же проблема. Решилось добавлением роли "Создатель проекта"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это баг, причину никто не знает. В настоящее время есть только один способ активировать OAuth-авторизацию - это создания приложения через Quickstart, https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python?authuser=2

На странице (ссылка выше) нужно нажать на "Enable Google Sheets API", выбрать тип приложения, и всё - приложение создано уже с активированном OAuth, вы можете подключить любой сервис, а Google Sheets API уже можно отключить, если он Вам не нужен

Answer (score 0):

Все стало еще более странно :) Перешел по ссылке https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python?authuser=2 из поста Мегакота, спасибо ему большое) Нажал что сказано, получил ошибку :

Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.

Попробовал на всякий случай опять создать Окно запроса доступа OAuth, и о чудо !!! Все сохранилось. Ничего не понял, но очень интересно)